ServAlias in Apache log
I have an apache 2.4.6 VirtualHost, that has one ServerName, and a lot of ServerAlias.
I'd like to find out which ServerAlias are really used.
I found a way to add the ServerName (%v) in the log file, but nothing for the ServerAlias : is there a way to retrieve this info ?

That should be the requested host name. So you want to add that header entry to the logs.

OK, I found a way to retrieve that :
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vhost_log "%v %{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"

the %{Host}i allows me to add the ServerAlias called in the logs
